# Should I put the name of proof reader in scientific manuscripts?

Tags: research-process, acknowledgement, proofreading

Should I acknowledge the person who has proof read my scientific paper and have contributed in the improvement of quality of manuscripts.

Comment: I can't see why not.

Comment: I've appeared in the acknowledgments of several papers for pointing out typos, minor bugs and misunderstandable statements. I don't think such a mention is necessary, but I certainly enjoyed being mentioned and I see no downside. (No one, to my knowledge, has ever been told that their work is not independent enough because they thank too many people in their acknowledgments! It rather shows that the work is interesting to many people or they are well-accepted in the community.)

Answer (score 1):

You should acknowledge all who made your paper possible. If that is too many to list, then you can be generic and write something along the lines of "I would like to acknowledge and thank all those who helped and contributed to my paper."

Comment: I am not convinced adding a staple text to each paper that adds zero information is helpful. On the contrary, it seems like this has a direct negative effect on the signal to noise ratio across paper contents.